# I have too much code here, want to short this

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to shorten this code to functions, maybe to an easy case where it only replaces the word in "string". I don't want 10,000 lines of code that you probably know how to shorten.
I am also asking for a small explanation as to what I want to learn better in `PHP` and `MySQL`

Of course, the code works, but you can see how much space it takes.

I need to shorten the code in `settings.php`

dbc.php

```
<?php
$DB_SERVER = 'localhost';
$DB_USERNAME = 'XXXX';
$DB_PASSWORD = 'XXXX';
$dev_db = mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER,$DB_USERNAME,$DB_PASSWORD,'sf');
$easy_db = mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER,$DB_USERNAME,$DB_PASSWORD,'easy');
$medium_db = mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER,$DB_USERNAME,$DB_PASSWORD,'medium');
$hard_db = mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER,$DB_USERNAME,$DB_PASSWORD,'hard');
```

settings.php

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 0);

include'dbc.php';

//Fix Znaków
function fixSpecialChars($text)
{

    $text = str_replace('/', '$s', $text);
    $text = str_replace('http://', 'http:$c$s$', $text);
    $text = str_replace('https://', 'https:$c$s$', $text);
    $text = str_replace('%40', '@', $text);

    return $text;
}

//Czas
$dt = date_timestamp_get(date_create()) - 1800;
$dt24 = date_timestamp_get(date_create()) - 86400;

//Aktywni dev
$dev_res = mysqli_query($dev_db, "SELECT ID, name, usysclass, banned FROM players WHERE poll >= $dt AND poll <= NOW() ORDER BY poll DESC");
$dev_res24 = mysqli_query($dev_db, "SELECT ID, name, usysclass, banned FROM players WHERE poll >= $dt24 AND poll <= NOW() ORDER BY poll DESC");
$dev_uno = mysqli_num_rows($dev_res);
$dev_uno24 = mysqli_num_rows($dev_res24);

$dev_user_counting = mysqli_query($dev_db, "SELECT count(*) as total_count from players");
$dev_user_count = mysqli_fetch_object($dev_user_counting);
$dev_all_acount = $dev_user_count->total_count;
$dev_all = $dev_all_acount + 0;

//Aktywni easy
$easy_res = mysqli_query($easy_db, "SELECT ID, name, usysclass, banned FROM players WHERE poll >= $dt AND poll <= NOW() ORDER BY poll DESC");
$easy_res24 = mysqli_query($easy_db, "SELECT ID, name, usysclass, banned FROM players WHERE poll >= $dt24 AND poll <= NOW() ORDER BY poll DESC");
$easy_uno = mysqli_num_rows($easy_res);
$easy_uno24 = mysqli_num_rows($easy_res24);

$easy_user_counting = mysqli_query($easy_db, "SELECT count(*) as total_count from players");
$easy_user_count = mysqli_fetch_object($easy_user_counting);
$easy_all_acount = $easy_user_count->total_count;
$easy_all = $easy_all_acount + 0;

//Aktywni medium
$medium_res = mysqli_query($medium_db, "SELECT ID, name, usysclass, banned FROM players WHERE poll >= $dt AND poll <= NOW() ORDER BY poll DESC");
$medium_res24 = mysqli_query($medium_db, "SELECT ID, name, usysclass, banned FROM players WHERE poll >= $dt24 AND poll <= NOW() ORDER BY poll DESC");
$medium_uno = mysqli_num_rows($medium_res);
$medium_uno24 = mysqli_num_rows($medium_res24);

$medium_user_counting = mysqli_query($medium_db, "SELECT count(*) as total_count from players");
$medium_user_count = mysqli_fetch_object($medium_user_counting);
$medium_all_acount = $medium_user_count->total_count;
$medium_all = $medium_all_acount + 0;

//Aktywni hard
$hard_res = mysqli_query($hard_db, "SELECT ID, name, usysclass, banned FROM players WHERE poll >= $dt AND poll <= NOW() ORDER BY poll DESC");
$hard_res24 = mysqli_query($hard_db, "SELECT ID, name, usysclass, banned FROM players WHERE poll >= $dt24 AND poll <= NOW() ORDER BY poll DESC");
$hard_uno = mysqli_num_rows($hard_res);
$hard_uno24 = mysqli_num_rows($hard_res24);

$hard_user_counting = mysqli_query($hard_db, "SELECT count(*) as total_count from players");
$hard_user_count = mysqli_fetch_object($hard_user_counting);
$hard_all_acount = $hard_user_count->total_count;
$hard_all = $hard_all_acount + 0;
```

home.php (My page)

```
<?php
include 'main.php';
checkLoggedIn();
head("Główna");
?>


    <div class="content">
        <h2>Home Page</h2>
        <p>Welcome back, <?= $_SESSION['name'] ?>!</p>
    </div>

<?php include 'settings.php' ?>


    <table style="width: 100%;" border="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-left: 0px;">
                <div class="content"><h2 style="text-align: center"><span>Wybierz serwer:</span></h2></div>
                <p class="news">
                <div id="sfmenu">
                    <div class="btn2_main">
                        <a href="http://sf.sgsie.pl/dev/">
                            <div class="sfbt">
                                Beta
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="sfmenu">

                    <div class="btn2_main">
                        <a href="X.php">
                            <div class="sfbt">
                                Easy
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn2_main">
                        <a href="X.php">
                            <div class="sfbt">
                                Medium
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn2_main">
                        <a href="X.php">
                            <div class="sfbt">
                                Hard
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table style="width: 100%;" border="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-left: 0px;">
                <div class="content"><h2 style="text-align: center"><span>Aktywni Gracze:</span></h2></div>
                <br>
                <p class="news">
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" class="tableinborder" summary="none"
                       width="600px">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><b><span style="color: #33cc00; font-size: small; ">Graczy online:</span>
                                <br>
                                <span>Dev: </span><span style="color: red; font-size: small; "><?= $dev_uno ?><span
                                            style="color: #33cc00; font-size: small; "> / </span><?= $dev_all ?></span></b>
                            <br>
                            <span>Easy: </span><span style="color: red; font-size: small; "><?= $easy_uno ?><span
                                        style="color: #33cc00; font-size: small; "> / </span><?= $easy_all ?></span></b>
                            <br>
                            <span>Medium: </span><span style="color: red; font-size: small; "><?= $medium_uno ?><span
                                        style="color: #33cc00; font-size: small; "> / </span><?= $medium_all ?></span></b>
                            <br>
                            <span>Hard: </span><span style="color: red; font-size: small; "><?= $hard_uno ?><span
                                        style="color: #33cc00; font-size: small; "> / </span><?= $hard_all ?></span></b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                <br>
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" class="tableinborder" summary="none"
                       width="600px">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><b><span style="color: #33cc00; font-size: small; ">Graczy online (24h):</span>
                                <br>
                                <span>Dev: </span><span style="color: red; font-size: small; "><?= $dev_uno24 ?><span
                                            style="color: #33cc00; font-size: small; "> / </span><?= $dev_all ?></span></b>
                            <br>
                            <span>Easy: </span><span style="color: red; font-size: small; "><?= $easy_uno24 ?><span
                                        style="color: #33cc00; font-size: small; "> / </span><?= $easy_all ?></span></b>
                            <br>
                            <span>Medium: </span><span style="color: red; font-size: small; "><?= $medium_uno24 ?><span
                                        style="color: #33cc00; font-size: small; "> / </span><?= $medium_all ?></span></b>
                            <br>
                            <span>Hard: </span><span style="color: red; font-size: small; "><?= $hard_uno24 ?><span
                                        style="color: #33cc00; font-size: small; "> / </span><?= $hard_all ?></span></b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php
foot();
?>
```

Comment: way too broad! There is much to comprehend in the code above - or try to comprehend and thus see a more concise solution. This does not look like a simple task

Comment: You really don't need 4 connections. You can write your sql commands with FROM sf.players to identify each group. then at least you can fpr for a loop where you only exchange the databse every round. You can also inner join a count(*) but that makes only the select command bigger

Comment: @nbk so i just change ```$dev_db = mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER,$DB_USERNAME,$DB_PASSWORD,'sf');```
to ```$db = mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER,$DB_USERNAME,$DB_PASSWORD);```
then i just use what you said right?

Comment: As i said use $dev_db = mysqli_connect($DB_SERVER,$DB_USERNAME,$DB_PASSWORD); and the use FROM sf.players or FROM easy.players to get the data from a specific database